# Permission Denied, while writing a image file file in Android SDcard

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am getting a problem while writing file at SDCARD. it shows as Permission denied.

I added    " uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" "

On my Manifest,

public static void takeScreenshotd(View view, String name)throws Exception{

```
     view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
     view.buildDrawingCache();
     String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
     Bitmap bitMap = view.getDrawingCache();
     FileOutputStream fos = null;
     File outputFile=new File(SCREENSHOT_LOCATION+name+"_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"jpg");

     try{
         File sddirFile = new File(SCREENSHOT_LOCATION);
         if (!sddirFile.exists())
         {
             new File(SCREENSHOT_LOCATION).mkdirs();
            // sddirFile.mkdirs();
         }
         if(!sddirFile.canWrite())
         {
            boolean dr = sddirFile.setWritable(true);
             String Ak ="Protected";
         }

     fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    // It is skip this place.. when i keep the bitmap.compress (it shows an error message as permission denied.
         if (fos!=null)
         {
             bitMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fos);
             fos.close();
         }

     }catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

 }
```

Comment: Have you added permission to write int SDCard in manifest file ?

Comment: Where did you add your `<uses-permission />` in your manifest? It should be outside the `<application />` tag. And which permission did you use?

Comment: yes. my Uses-permission is outside the Application tag

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

but still the same

Comment: Are you using android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" in manifest?

Answer (score 5):

Check whether you have added this permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Edit your question appropriately. I am not able to see the permission you have described.

Comment: If you are using emulator it is really a bit odd to set the permissions manually to it. You night have to check it in a real device